# Book for .Net Web Services

Tags: c#

Can any one suggest me a good book for .Net Web Services beginers (C#)

Comment: Amazon is your friend here...http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Hands-Michele-Leroux-Bustamante/dp/0596101627/ref=pd_sim_b_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this book, very highly recommended and current

[ASP.NET 4 in C# and VB.NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0041D8V62)

If you're looking for WCF, this one is great:

[Essential WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321440064)

Answer (score 2):

If you're only just starting to do web services, I would strongly recommend you go and check out WCF. It's the current and future standard for communications between machines - web services and a lot more.

The book I always recommend to get up and running in WCF quickly is [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627) by Michele Leroux Bustamante. She covers all the necessary topics, and in a very understandable and approachable way. This will teach you everything - basics, intermediate topics, security, transaction control and so forth - that you need to know to write high quality, useful WCF services.

[image: Learning WCF]

The more advanced topics and more in-depth look at WCF will be covered by [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308) by Juval Lowy. He really dives into all technical details and topics and presents "the bible" for WCF programming. He just recently completed a [third edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489), which covers WCF in .NET 4 and AppFabric and the Azure Service Bus, too.

[image: Programming WCF Services including AppFabric and Azure ServiceBus]

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to WCF services then I would recommend the following book

Programming WCF Services, Third Edition
Mastering WCF and the Azure AppFabric Service Bus
ByJuval Lowy

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805494/

Comment: That's more of an advanced book, however... great book - but not necessarily for beginners...